# Quote to Order Reference in punchout

Tags: xml, e-commerce, cxml-commercexml

I am trying to figure out how to maintain the quote to order reference when a buyer retrieves a quote/order from my punchout catalog.

What I mean by this is, when the supplier catalog sends back the products to the buyer's requisition system in a "PunchoutOrderMessage" There is no place for the supplier to enter a quote id.  I have looked through the cxml spec but I am not seeing anything.  Am I missing something?

I have included a sample "punchoutordermessage". Can anyone help me figure out how to send a quote ID back to the buyer?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="2008-12-24T10:46:32-06:00@www.test.com" xml:lang="en-US" timestamp="2008-12-24T10:46:32-06:00">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>testcompany</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>testsite</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain="www.testsite.com">
        <Identity>PunchoutResponse</Identity>
      </Credential>
      <UserAgent>PunchoutSite</UserAgent>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <PunchOutOrderMessage>
      <BuyerCookie>PSFT_2008-12-24T10:44:00-06:00</BuyerCookie>
      <PunchOutOrderMessageHeader operationAllowed="edit">
        <Total>
          <Money currency="USD">205.34</Money>
        </Total>
      </PunchOutOrderMessageHeader>
      <ItemIn quantity="2">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>123</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID />
        </ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>
          <UnitPrice>
            <Money currency="USD">102.67</Money>
          </UnitPrice>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">PRESSURE GAUGE</Description>
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
          <Classification domain="UNSPSC">123</Classification>
          <ManufacturerPartID>123</ManufacturerPartID>
          <ManufacturerName>testManufacturer</ManufacturerName>
        </ItemDetail>
      </ItemIn>
    </PunchOutOrderMessage>
  </Message>
</cXML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to use the extrinsic elements.

```
    <ItemIn quantity="1"> 
         <ItemDetail> 
           <UnitPrice> 
               <Money currency="USD">1.23</Money> 
          </UnitPrice> 
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">product 123</Description> 
          <UnitOfMeasure>FT</UnitOfMeasure> 
          <Classification domain="UNSPSC">31151601</Classification> 
          <ManufacturerPartID>1234</ManufacturerPartID> 
          <ManufacturerName>Test Company</ManufacturerName> 
          <Extrinsic name="QuoteId">12345</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="QuoteLine">1</Extrinsic>
         </ItemDetail> 
   </ItemIn>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "SupplierPartAuxiliaryID" node is designed to be used by the supplier for whatever data you would like to pass with the quote (punchoutordermessage) that will be stored with the order through requisition mgmt, transferred to the PO,and returned to you with the ordermessage. This is where you can send your quote id (or quote id/line number).

Comment: Thanks, for the response. I will be testing this out in the next couple weeks, it it works, I'll come back and mark it as an answer

Comment: I have actually done a little more research on this and I don't think this is the right way to do this...  I will come back with another update once we are complete with this implementation.